# Electrostatics, measurement of charge

Tags: charge, conventions, si-units, metrology

How did physicists come up with a standard for measuring charge? How an electrical measurement  of charge was made?

Answer (score 0):

You can of course find this on wiki...or many other places.

Today, charge is related to the elementary charge *e*

The SI unit of charge, the coulomb, "is the quantity of electricity carried in 1 second by a current of 1 ampere A". Conversely, a current of one ampere is one coulomb C of charge going past a given point per second:

$1 A = 1 \frac{C}{s}$

The Ampere is defined by the elementary charge, see e.g. wiki for more detail than you probably want.

Practical measurement - if you have a capacitor of known strength, you can measure the charge on it with a voltmeter.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am unable to understand this. When charges were discovered and a mathematical equation involving charges is not known , what reference standard was chosen to represent 1 C of charge?

Comment: In June 1785 Coulomb measured the electric force.  https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/201606/physicshistory.cfm  If what you are asking is how did he come up with the constant, that has been asked before https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243259/which-was-the-first-coulombs-constant-value